# Tensor flow serving docker invalid field

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

When running the sample example in tensorflow model server [https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker](Serving example part)

```
docker run -p 8501:8501   --mount type=bind,  source=serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu,  target=/models/half_plus_two   -e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two -t tensorflow/serving &
```

the following error comes

```
See 'docker run --help'.
[1]+  Exit 125
```

docker --version gives
Docker version 18.06.1-ce

The model server docker image is the latest version as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The command shouldn't have spaces after the commas.

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu,target=/models/half_plus_two -e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two -t tensorflow/serving &
```